# Count clicks of specific Button

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm writing function for counting click of red background's button. 
This function is not working.
I have 40 buttons with the same function for click "ButClick". 
But when I click any button (for example with green background) - counter counts. I want to do it only when I will click button with red background.

```
private void But_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var column = Grid.GetColumn(sender as Button);
    var row = Grid.GetRow(sender as Button);
    LabelX.Content = column.ToString();
    LabelY.Content = row.ToString();

    if ((sender as Button).Background == new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
    {
        counts += 1;
        LabelCounterOfClick.Content = counts.ToString();
    }

}
```

---

**update**

Now it's not counting anything. When i click any button- counter show 0. I thing something with function if is wrong(it not detect Red)

```
private void But_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    var column = Grid.GetColumn(sender as Button); 
    var row = Grid.GetRow(sender as Button); 
    LabelX.Content = column.ToString(); 
    LabelY.Content = row.ToString();

    if ((sender as Button).Background == new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red))
    {
        counts += 1;

    }
    else
    {
        counts = 0;
    }

    LabelCounterOfClick.Content = counts.ToString(); 
}
```

**REst of Code.**

```
namespace Silnik_Zmiany_koloru
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Random _random;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
            dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            dt.Tick += Dt_Tick;
            dt.Start();
        }

        private void Dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Losowanie(); // zmiana kolorow (losowe)
        }
        int counts = 0;


        private void But0_0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Losowanie();
        }

        private Random random = new Random();
        private Random random1 = new Random();

        int ilosc_kolorow = 3;
        private Color[] colors = new Color[]
               {
               Colors.Red,
               Colors.Blue,
               Colors.Green,
               };


        private void Losowanie()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 3; k <= 10; k++)
                {
                    var ele = MainGrid.FindName("But" + i + "_" + random.Next(0, 8));
                    Button button = ele as Button;
                    if (button != null)
                    {
                        Change_color(button);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you console.write (sender as Button).Background while clicking the red button?

Comment: Are you sure that the `else` condition did not reset it to 0?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing **;** at the end of the line after if condition

and you can check the background with "**Brushes.Red**" instead of create new object

Comment: Excellent observation. when we try to solve some major problems, we normally end up ignoring small mistakes !

Comment: Ok, better, but now counter not counting anything.

Comment: @MichałŁahchim Please post your updated code and specify exactly where it is going wrong, e.g. is the `if`-statement returning false when you expect it not to? Or is something else going wrong?

Comment: @MichałŁahchim when you draw the button set the background to "**Brushes.Red**" and then Compare in the Btn_Click with **== Brushes.Red**

Comment: No, im  setting it by function:         "private void Change_color(Button name)
        {
            name.Background = new SolidColorBrush(colors[rand.Next(0, ilosc_kolorow)]);
        }"

Comment: what's the colors in put the **colors** list ?

Comment: @AbduGo , he cannot directly compare `Background` with `Brushes.Red` .  he have to convert properties of them to String first. see my answer.

Comment: @amit Thanks! WORKS!

Comment: @MichałŁahchim depend on Colors List, you should compare with **Colors.Red**, 
Amit Code work because he convert the color first to string and compare string with string, (y)

Answer (score 2):

Why have you attached the ButClick event to all 40 buttons? Why not just add it to those red?
Select properties on the button and assign click event to those that should have it.

Comment: Because i want to make function for counting click of Red buttons. So this is the reason why i'm using one function for 40 buttons.

Comment: @MichałŁahchim I think what random means is that, if you ONLY attach the `But_Click` to red buttons, then you don't need to worry about checking if the event sender is red or not, as only red buttons will fire the event

Comment: @Bassie Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Bassie ok- but i'm begginer in Visual Studio- and i do not know how to do it.

Comment: @MichałŁahchim you must have connected the click event to every button, otherwise nothing will happen. If you're working with Windows forms you can click on the button in designer view and select properties of the button, disconnect the event of the unwanted buttons. If you're working in wpf xaml you can basically remove the OnClicked="But_Click" in the xaml code of the unwanted buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Keep correction of AbduGo in mind.

Not the best solution but Try doing this,

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        Brush btnBrush = btn.Background;
        string color = "";
        if (btnBrush is SolidColorBrush)
        {
            color = ((SolidColorBrush)btnBrush).Color.ToString();
        }

        if (color ==  Brushes.Red.ToString())
        {
           //your logic of incrementing counter
        }
        else
        {
           //your logic of resting counter
        }
    }
```